# HTTP Basic-Auth and 401 error

Tags: php, curl

Trying to connect to a remote service, with the use of authorization (basic):

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://online.moysklad.ru/exchange/xml/import');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'login:password');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'file' => '@'. ROOT .'/moysklad.xml',
    'resolveByCode' => 'resolveByCode',
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    echo curl_error($curl);
    exit();
}
curl_close($curl);
```

And always get 401 error. What's wrong?

Comment: Maybe your login and password are wrong? Have you confirmed them manually using a browser?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 401 -> Unauthorized, you are using the wrong username or password.

Comment: Did you tested it as Pekka said in your browser?